# iOS, TabBar and NavigationBar got hidden after adding pushViewController

Tags: ios

I want to pass the variable " uid " between the FirstViewController and SecondViewController, so I used the following code to pass it. It successfully pass it, but the problem it hides the NavigationBar and the TabBar !

How can I solve it?

> ```
>   SecondViewController *vc2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
>      vc2.uid = uid;
>      [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2  animated:YES];
> ```

Comment: If you don't pass the variable then the navigation bar and tab bar is visible?

Comment: What does your SecondViewController look like?

Comment: @AbdullahShafique yes exactly !

Comment: @berentrom contains a Tabbar, navigationBar. I use this to see if uid is passed : 

`NSLog(@"uid is : %@",_uid);`

Comment: @user3340961 Do you do anything with that variable in your Second View Controller? Also can you show the code in your Second View Controller?

Comment: @AbdullahShafique The FirstViewController is a login screen with, 2 fields (email, password) after receiving the success login from my jSON file, it gives success, with the `uid` the idea here is that I want to pass this `uid` inside the app to use it in other tab, so that It shows the content depending on the `uid`.

Comment: @AbdullahShafique, the SecondViewController contains `- (void)viewDidLoad { NSLog(@"uid is : %@",_uid); }`

Comment: @user3340961 Thats it? No other code?

Comment: @AbdullahShafique, yes I've just begin on it, so I am only doing tests now. But I am stuck on this thing.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use storyboard segues to solve this? Just embed you view controller on a Navigation View controller and call `performSegueWithIdentifier` function.

Just add prepareForSegue function to your class and set uid there:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender: (id) sender
{

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"secondViewSegue"])
    {

    //**OPTION A**: If you are using Push segue

    SecondViewController *secondVC = (SecondViewController
*)segue.destinationViewController;

    //**OPTION B**: ***ELSE, If you are using a Modal segue

    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*)segue.destinationViewController;

    SecondViewController *secondVC = (SessionViewController *)navController.topViewController;

    //END OF OPTION B

    secondVc.uid = uidValue;

    }

}
```

Comment: I've already done that, but when using performSegueWithIdentifier, I can not pass uid.

Comment: Complementing the answer :)

Comment: Did you try again using prepareForSegue function?